# How to escape < and > in YAML/Jekyll?

Tags: yaml, escaping, jekyll

I'm trying to escape the characters < and >, e.g. in:

```
description: "some file <x> bla bla"
```

Note: x should be generated literally.
The generated HTML code always generates a `<li>` and/or `<ul>`, because of the < and >, which clearly should not happen.

What I tried is:

- Using " (like above)
- Using '
- using escape characters like \
- using unicode form like \x..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML escaping should do the trick:

```
description: "some file &lt;x&gt; bla bla"
```

Comment: This works thanks ... In all examples and documentation I did not find this method.

Comment: I am giving this +1 because this answer solves the problem.  But the messy raw html given in this answer is exactly what tools like Jekyll are meant to eliminate.  It took a long time for us to search through every location of `<` and `>` in a website to make judgement calls about when and when not to apply the messy code in this answer. 
 There should be an solution like escaping with `\\`